# phpseclib and Synology NAS SCP failure

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp, phpseclib, synology

I am attempting to scp a file onto a Synology NAS (into the /tmp directory). Doing this from the command line of my Ubuntu machine works as intended. Running the PHP code works as intended against a regular Linux distro (as in every distro I've tried - Ubuntu, Debian, Centos, Redhat, Suse, Arch). Even against other *nix it's fine (MacOS, AIX, etc). I don't think it's a PHPSecLib issue as such, but that's what we're using. Ubuntu 18.04 to Synology DS3615xs running DSM 6.1.7-15284. The credentials are correct. The user has write permission on /tmp. I have posted the full log (it's a test Synology that is unused). Any assistance would be most appreciated.

If I run the scp from the shell of my Ubuntu machine, I get the below logs and it works as intended.

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.22 ([192.168.1.22]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /tmp/
Sending file modes: C0775 117453 audit_linux.sh
Sink: C0775 117453 audit_linux.sh
audit_linux.sh                                                                                            100%  115KB  26.7MB/s   00:00    
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 121156, received 2696 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1608483.9, received 35792.5
debug1: Exit status 0
```

The full PHPSecLib logs are below.

```
<-
00000000 53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:4f:70:65:6e:53:53:48:5f SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_
00000010 36:2e:38:70:31:2d:68:70:6e:31:34:76:36:0d:0a 6.8p1-hpn14v6..

->
00000000 53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:70:68:70:73:65:63:6c:69 SSH-2.0-phpsecli
00000010 62:5f:31:2e:30:20:28:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:6c:29:0d b_1.0 (openssl).
00000020 0a .

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.0338, network: 0.0008s)
00000000 54:40:f5:21:15:4b:dc:60:c7:81:0c:87:a3:0b:2e:c8 T@.!.K.`........
00000010 00:00:00:96:63:75:72:76:65:32:35:35:31:39:2d:73 ....curve25519-s
00000020 68:61:32:35:36:40:6c:69:62:73:73:68:2e:6f:72:67 ha256@libssh.org
00000030 2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69:73:74:70 ,ecdh-sha2-nistp
00000040 32:35:36:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69 256,ecdh-sha2-ni
00000050 73:74:70:33:38:34:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32 stp384,ecdh-sha2
00000060 2d:6e:69:73:74:70:35:32:31:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65 -nistp521,diffie
00000070 2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:2d:65 -hellman-group-e
00000080 78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:32:35:36:2c:64 xchange-sha256,d
00000090 69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72 iffie-hellman-gr
000000a0 6f:75:70:31:34:2d:73:68:61:31:00:00:00:2f:73:73 oup14-sha1.../ss
000000b0 68:2d:72:73:61:2c:73:73:68:2d:64:73:73:2c:65:63 h-rsa,ssh-dss,ec
000000c0 64:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69:73:74:70:32:35 dsa-sha2-nistp25
000000d0 36:2c:73:73:68:2d:65:64:32:35:35:31:39:00:00:00 6,ssh-ed25519...
000000e0 6c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31 laes128-ctr,aes1
000000f0 39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74 92-ctr,aes256-ct
00000100 72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65 r,aes128-gcm@ope
00000110 6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d nssh.com,aes256-
00000120 67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c gcm@openssh.com,
00000130 63:68:61:63:68:61:32:30:2d:70:6f:6c:79:31:33:30 chacha20-poly130
00000140 35:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00 5@openssh.com...
00000150 6c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31 laes128-ctr,aes1
00000160 39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74 92-ctr,aes256-ct
00000170 72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65 r,aes128-gcm@ope
00000180 6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d nssh.com,aes256-
00000190 67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c gcm@openssh.com,
000001a0 63:68:61:63:68:61:32:30:2d:70:6f:6c:79:31:33:30 chacha20-poly130
000001b0 35:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00 5@openssh.com...
000001c0 d5:75:6d:61:63:2d:36:34:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65 .umac-64-etm@ope
000001d0 6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32 nssh.com,umac-12
000001e0 38:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f 8-etm@openssh.co
000001f0 6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2d m,hmac-sha2-256-
00000200 65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c etm@openssh.com,
00000210 68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2d:65:74 hmac-sha2-512-et
00000220 6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d m@openssh.com,hm
00000230 61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e ac-sha1-etm@open
00000240 73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36:34:40 ssh.com,umac-64@
00000250 6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63 openssh.com,umac
00000260 2d:31:32:38:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d -128@openssh.com
00000270 2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68 ,hmac-sha2-256,h
00000280 6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2c:68:6d:61 mac-sha2-512,hma
00000290 63:2d:73:68:61:31:00:00:00:d5:75:6d:61:63:2d:36 c-sha1....umac-6
000002a0 34:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f 4-etm@openssh.co
000002b0 6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f m,umac-128-etm@o
000002c0 70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d penssh.com,hmac-
000002d0 73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65 sha2-256-etm@ope
000002e0 6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68 nssh.com,hmac-sh
000002f0 61:32:2d:35:31:32:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73 a2-512-etm@opens
00000300 73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31 sh.com,hmac-sha1
00000310 2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d -etm@openssh.com
00000320 2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36:34:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68 ,umac-64@openssh
00000330 2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:40:6f:70 .com,umac-128@op
00000340 65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73 enssh.com,hmac-s
00000350 68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61 ha2-256,hmac-sha
00000360 32:2d:35:31:32:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:00 2-512,hmac-sha1.
00000370 00:00:15:6e:6f:6e:65:2c:7a:6c:69:62:40:6f:70:65 ...none,zlib@ope
00000380 6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00:15:6e:6f:6e:65 nssh.com....none
00000390 2c:7a:6c:69:62:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f ,zlib@openssh.co
000003a0 6d:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 m.............

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000 a6:3e:b5:ac:c5:0a:b6:44:3a:11:34:4a:99:be:1b:a1 .>.....D:.4J....
00000010 00:00:00:7e:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d ...~diffie-hellm
00000020 61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64 an-group1-sha1,d
00000030 69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72 iffie-hellman-gr
00000040 6f:75:70:31:34:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69:66:66:69 oup14-sha1,diffi
00000050 65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:2d e-hellman-group-
00000060 65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69 exchange-sha1,di
00000070 66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f ffie-hellman-gro
00000080 75:70:2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:32 up-exchange-sha2
00000090 35:36:00:00:00:0f:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:2c:73:73 56....ssh-rsa,ss
000000a0 68:2d:64:73:73:00:00:00:d3:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d h-dss....aes128-
000000b0 63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61 ctr,aes192-ctr,a
000000c0 65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73 es256-ctr,twofis
000000d0 68:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68 h128-ctr,twofish
000000e0 31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:32 192-ctr,twofish2
000000f0 35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:62 56-ctr,aes128-cb
00000100 63:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73 c,aes192-cbc,aes
00000110 32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31 256-cbc,twofish1
00000120 32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39 28-cbc,twofish19
00000130 32:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36 2-cbc,twofish256
00000140 2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63 -cbc,twofish-cbc
00000150 2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:74:72:2c:62:6c ,blowfish-ctr,bl
00000160 6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:2c:33:64:65:73:2d owfish-cbc,3des-
00000170 63:74:72:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:62:63:00:00:00:d3 ctr,3des-cbc....
00000180 61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:39 aes128-ctr,aes19
00000190 32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72 2-ctr,aes256-ctr
000001a0 2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c ,twofish128-ctr,
000001b0 74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:74 twofish192-ctr,t
000001c0 77:6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65 wofish256-ctr,ae
000001d0 73:31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d s128-cbc,aes192-
000001e0 63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:74 cbc,aes256-cbc,t
000001f0 77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77 wofish128-cbc,tw
00000200 6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f ofish192-cbc,two
00000210 66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66 fish256-cbc,twof
00000220 69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68 ish-cbc,blowfish
00000230 2d:63:74:72:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62 -ctr,blowfish-cb
00000240 63:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:74:72:2c:33:64:65:73:2d c,3des-ctr,3des-
00000250 63:62:63:00:00:00:39:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32 cbc...9hmac-sha2
00000260 2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:39 -256,hmac-sha1-9
00000270 36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:68:6d:61:63 6,hmac-sha1,hmac
00000280 2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35 -md5-96,hmac-md5
00000290 00:00:00:39:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35 ...9hmac-sha2-25
000002a0 36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:39:36:2c:68 6,hmac-sha1-96,h
000002b0 6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64 mac-sha1,hmac-md
000002c0 35:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:00:00:00 5-96,hmac-md5...
000002d0 04:6e:6f:6e:65:00:00:00:04:6e:6f:6e:65:00:00:00 .none....none...
000002e0 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 ..........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT (since last: 0.0329, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:01:00:3a:81:ea:6d:6a:ca:ec:5f:8d:7d:7f:7d ....:..mj.._.}.}
00000010 18:82:47:7f:60:bc:f9:0a:9a:2a:d8:4f:09:62:5f:82 ..G.`....*.O.b_.
00000020 79:ef:a3:5e:2a:b2:d7:91:42:ba:3a:88:a8:82:6e:7a y..^*...B.:...nz
00000030 19:53:e5:80:09:a9:61:fd:14:7e:b8:ef:3e:c5:c1:35 .S....a..~..>..5
00000040 8a:de:b6:75:58:d9:cb:d9:c9:8b:ce:b8:f2:05:42:5a ...uX.........BZ
00000050 7d:9c:01:1b:e2:c9:bc:d3:f5:a5:55:6a:c4:4a:03:40 }.........Uj.J.@
00000060 ae:53:01:ef:30:e0:41:6b:4d:54:1d:72:a8:47:bb:70 .S..0.AkMT.r.G.p
00000070 47:95:73:0c:1c:16:3e:a9:6a:e0:f7:6d:04:d4:e1:b6 G.s...>.j..m....
00000080 22:97:c8:07:5a:04:2c:85:af:ca:3e:dc:e2:77:62:6b "...Z.,...>..wbk
00000090 6c:8c:1a:57:49:9e:d3:0d:13:e3:b6:cc:18:4e:69:28 l..WI........Ni(
000000a0 be:6c:bf:63:2c:5e:b6:23:6f:fc:50:03:b2:53:da:e6 .l.c,^.#o.P..S..
000000b0 d0:64:db:41:35:08:50:8c:41:ce:f6:e9:97:66:9f:04 .d.A5.P.A....f..
000000c0 79:2f:60:b1:28:7d:4d:15:a6:a4:5e:fd:c7:11:41:a6 y/`.(}M...^...A.
000000d0 bd:89:8c:15:a3:e0:b1:4f:a3:dc:e5:45:06:e6:f0:40 .......O...E...@
000000e0 2e:61:6e:7f:0a:e8:67:0f:b9:04:8d:e8:42:78:f5:c6 .an...g.....Bx..
000000f0 e5:a5:99:7a:58:6d:0e:9c:8e:af:d7:98:bc:e6:6c:cf ...zXm........l.
00000100 e8:1b:f3:e9 ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY (since last: 0.0087, network: 0.0087s)
00000000 00:00:01:17:00:00:00:07:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:00 ........ssh-rsa.
00000010 00:00:03:01:00:01:00:00:01:01:00:d5:fe:2b:bc:8a .............+..
00000020 f6:16:8f:16:bd:9e:a8:f4:56:bf:5d:88:8b:34:c6:63 ........V.]..4.c
00000030 cf:6d:f3:01:a1:41:f8:b9:20:2c:5f:7e:61:36:9f:10 .m...A.. ,_~a6..
00000040 ff:d3:4b:cf:b9:f1:83:73:6e:36:8a:db:56:f1:20:de ..K....sn6..V. .
00000050 12:a8:88:26:33:07:2a:98:c7:14:dd:81:ce:a2:27:7f ...&3.*.......'.
00000060 b9:2d:27:3e:a6:12:61:1c:9a:ab:d9:cd:59:e6:0c:ba .-'>..a.....Y...
00000070 67:b6:27:ba:d1:c8:00:34:36:1d:d7:60:f5:09:57:ba g.'....46..`..W.
00000080 97:27:a0:8c:7b:4d:36:07:42:c5:4c:9e:c7:22:43:04 .'..{M6.B.L.."C.
00000090 ef:26:82:40:70:55:0f:a1:4a:7e:9e:f7:1b:fa:3d:9a .&.@pU..J~....=.
000000a0 52:da:d0:13:66:d6:f4:0c:bf:2f:35:d5:05:64:22:d0 R...f..../5..d".
000000b0 dc:a9:0d:d7:e0:b9:0a:5c:3e:b0:aa:7d:ca:a8:3a:18 .......\>..}..:.
000000c0 55:17:af:3e:63:42:73:94:49:c8:65:34:a2:0d:a8:5b U..>cBs.I.e4...[
000000d0 49:d7:54:76:06:6c:46:b4:6e:46:ed:68:ae:d1:fe:b8 I.Tv.lF.nF.h....
000000e0 c4:30:b5:ad:c9:47:86:16:93:08:ab:d0:4c:67:7f:d9 .0...G......Lg..
000000f0 12:32:c9:ef:3f:b5:f6:40:1e:a6:89:c8:46:8c:0c:4a .2..?..@....F..J
00000100 45:b1:6b:69:7a:b7:4e:21:2f:d4:4f:30:07:32:72:b0 E.kiz.N!/.O0.2r.
00000110 00:15:e1:c6:d6:98:db:72:ba:54:87:00:00:01:01:00 .......r.T......
00000120 8d:da:a5:75:d2:92:15:17:8c:f5:07:6a:0f:b3:b4:47 ...u.......j...G
00000130 fe:22:bd:95:c4:b6:1c:81:86:bb:6f:e0:17:48:b7:c6 ."........o..H..
00000140 0d:9c:0c:2e:1c:25:a6:13:d9:5e:62:ea:10:79:20:43 .....%...^b..y C
00000150 07:4c:81:92:2d:f9:f9:a9:90:09:49:9e:c9:0d:fb:7e .L..-.....I....~
00000160 fe:73:8f:e3:73:86:cb:ef:71:17:ec:1e:d3:2c:15:b6 .s..s...q....,..
00000170 e0:b1:25:29:45:e4:8b:ea:94:fc:ab:77:87:39:85:09 ..%)E......w.9..
00000180 63:19:0f:88:24:f6:52:51:a2:d1:11:6f:45:53:67:f3 c...$.RQ...oESg.
00000190 73:86:b6:f1:a2:8b:f8:86:cb:36:58:f4:1b:f4:11:ce s........6X.....
000001a0 c1:dc:1d:b0:9f:36:ca:77:1b:63:36:b1:67:36:e7:e6 .....6.w.c6.g6..
000001b0 1f:a9:2d:9d:ed:ae:80:47:5b:ea:21:ef:45:b7:83:41 ..-....G[.!.E..A
000001c0 59:75:86:ef:4e:02:ee:4e:e2:15:a9:82:dc:5b:ab:b0 Yu..N..N.....[..
000001d0 8d:24:0b:95:91:d6:81:10:e2:74:29:ee:b9:8b:36:de .$.......t)...6.
000001e0 89:bc:ee:38:e0:f7:3b:25:f2:f0:84:f9:53:24:f6:c0 ...8..;%....S$..
000001f0 4a:ac:ce:81:5d:05:56:7c:80:cd:d3:4a:df:07:80:74 J...].V|...J...t
00000200 12:b5:d4:3f:11:8f:ec:de:07:0a:f4:6e:34:b8:12:b1 ...?.......n4...
00000210 67:b8:0a:11:4b:e5:7a:47:86:f3:00:e5:6b:73:11:2d g...K.zG....ks.-
00000220 00:00:01:0f:00:00:00:07:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:00 ........ssh-rsa.
00000230 00:01:00:63:0c:41:98:b6:08:8b:40:4b:c4:1a:52:3c ...c.A....@K..R.
00000240 cc:f9:b9:5d:d7:d3:5e:50:cd:ee:68:2a:06:55:26:0a ...]..^P..h*.U&.
00000250 8e:62:6a:3e:7e:1a:05:45:ca:a4:22:f3:24:8a:63:46 .bj>~..E..".$.cF
00000260 51:6a:82:9a:e2:5f:70:96:a0:04:10:c6:41:20:8f:d0 Qj..._p.....A ..
00000270 bd:12:c2:ce:28:bd:e2:ee:09:e2:2b:2b:69:0b:83:e9 ....(.....++i...
00000280 75:e0:7e:95:0e:b9:67:02:79:c2:1b:59:f4:07:20:03 u.~...g.y..Y.. .
00000290 8a:08:b0:6b:e2:b3:1e:9a:75:3c:dd:c6:20:09:5d:41 ...k....u... .]A
000002a0 2b:cb:2e:16:5a:3a:81:36:04:fa:f7:13:fc:81:3d:4c +...Z:.6......=L
000002b0 2f:69:b9:0e:5e:86:ce:19:a7:16:3f:3b:85:78:c5:63 /i..^.....?;.x.c
000002c0 65:6a:67:f6:9a:b9:1a:b7:48:cd:81:e0:12:7c:12:41 ejg.....H....|.A
000002d0 1a:fe:4a:b8:c9:cb:05:c0:7b:22:bf:b1:b5:8a:d4:36 ..J.....{".....6
000002e0 1a:dd:95:46:56:08:a5:86:71:d6:71:24:9a:4a:94:4e ...FV...q.q$.J.N
000002f0 18:1f:63:4f:7d:86:c1:5e:22:da:6a:67:0a:ff:85:51 ..cO}..^".jg...Q
00000300 09:5e:50:fc:de:60:bc:c9:18:80:49:95:ab:e4:29:35 .^P..`....I...)5
00000310 24:48:df:c1:de:4a:8a:1f:37:6a:d3:39:73:40:70:1e $H...J..7j.9s@p.
00000320 e8:8c:0a:a7:9e:3e:0d:02:d9:10:4e:ff:f2:c2:b9:59 .....>....N....Y
00000330 12:be:00 ...

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0.0354, network: 0s)


<- NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0, network: 0s)


-> NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST (since last: 0.0003, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68 ....ssh-userauth

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT (since last: 0.0393, network: 0.0393s)
00000000 00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68 ....ssh-userauth

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:00:08:75:73:65:72:6e:61:6d:65:00:00:00:0e ....username....
00000010 73:73:68:2d:63:6f:6e:6e:65:63:74:69:6f:6e:00:00 ssh-connection..
00000020 00:08:70:61:73:73:77:6f:72:64:00:00:00:00:08:70 ..password.....p
00000030 61:73:73:77:6f:72:64 assword

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS (since last: 0.028, network: 0.028s)


-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:00:07:73:65:73:73:69:6f:6e:00:00:01:00:7f ....session.....
00000010 ff:ff:ff:00:00:40:00 .....@.

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_GLOBAL_REQUEST (since last: 0.001, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:00:17:68:6f:73:74:6b:65:79:73:2d:30:30:40 ....hostkeys-00@
00000010 6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00:01:17 openssh.com.....
00000020 00:00:00:07:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:00:00:00:03:01 ....ssh-rsa.....
00000030 00:01:00:00:01:01:00:d5:fe:2b:bc:8a:f6:16:8f:16 .........+......
00000040 bd:9e:a8:f4:56:bf:5d:88:8b:34:c6:63:cf:6d:f3:01 ....V.]..4.c.m..
00000050 a1:41:f8:b9:20:2c:5f:7e:61:36:9f:10:ff:d3:4b:cf .A.. ,_~a6....K.
00000060 b9:f1:83:73:6e:36:8a:db:56:f1:20:de:12:a8:88:26 ...sn6..V. ....&
00000070 33:07:2a:98:c7:14:dd:81:ce:a2:27:7f:b9:2d:27:3e 3.*.......'..-'>
00000080 a6:12:61:1c:9a:ab:d9:cd:59:e6:0c:ba:67:b6:27:ba ..a.....Y...g.'.
00000090 d1:c8:00:34:36:1d:d7:60:f5:09:57:ba:97:27:a0:8c ...46..`..W..'..
000000a0 7b:4d:36:07:42:c5:4c:9e:c7:22:43:04:ef:26:82:40 {M6.B.L.."C..&.@
000000b0 70:55:0f:a1:4a:7e:9e:f7:1b:fa:3d:9a:52:da:d0:13 pU..J~....=.R...
000000c0 66:d6:f4:0c:bf:2f:35:d5:05:64:22:d0:dc:a9:0d:d7 f..../5..d".....
000000d0 e0:b9:0a:5c:3e:b0:aa:7d:ca:a8:3a:18:55:17:af:3e ...\>..}..:.U..>
000000e0 63:42:73:94:49:c8:65:34:a2:0d:a8:5b:49:d7:54:76 cBs.I.e4...[I.Tv
000000f0 06:6c:46:b4:6e:46:ed:68:ae:d1:fe:b8:c4:30:b5:ad .lF.nF.h.....0..
00000100 c9:47:86:16:93:08:ab:d0:4c:67:7f:d9:12:32:c9:ef .G......Lg...2..
00000110 3f:b5:f6:40:1e:a6:89:c8:46:8c:0c:4a:45:b1:6b:69 ?..@....F..JE.ki
00000120 7a:b7:4e:21:2f:d4:4f:30:07:32:72:b0:00:15:e1:c6 z.N!/.O0.2r.....
00000130 d6:98:db:72:ba:54:87:00:00:01:b1:00:00:00:07:73 ...r.T.........s
00000140 73:68:2d:64:73:73:00:00:00:81:00:b4:96:06:e1:66 sh-dss.........f
00000150 0e:7b:c8:41:44:ed:0f:57:12:38:72:a2:e0:9c:29:b9 .{.AD..W.8r...).
00000160 b2:a6:8a:e2:de:32:a7:4e:55:7b:88:16:1d:b4:76:2f .....2.NU{....v/
00000170 ac:02:cc:c2:91:8f:b7:a2:e2:d0:0c:be:2e:ef:14:fe ................
00000180 83:c7:8f:25:5c:c3:39:3c:bc:cd:4c:22:9b:1a:f3:61 ...%\.9...L"...a
00000190 ab:17:e8:62:98:31:9c:9c:40:e8:72:46:ea:84:97:c7 ...b.1..@.rF....
000001a0 af:cb:3b:ee:97:3d:6b:4e:f3:2a:d5:95:07:91:9f:a6 ..;..=kN.*......
000001b0 07:6f:a8:46:37:5f:52:c6:f1:be:51:4d:11:eb:c0:d7 .o.F7_R...QM....
000001c0 90:af:32:43:b8:a8:d6:6e:6d:ef:91:00:00:00:15:00 ..2C...nm.......
000001d0 f8:44:03:10:69:61:88:e7:93:61:eb:b3:a4:63:d8:a0 .D..ia...a...c..
000001e0 5d:ef:ff:2d:00:00:00:80:75:64:d2:f0:e9:fe:f0:a0 ]..-....ud......
000001f0 2d:50:43:c9:e8:8a:03:2b:ee:6a:db:c1:b6:66:a6:7d -PC....+.j...f.}
00000200 7f:20:a8:1a:52:ca:67:25:43:c2:43:bc:2f:e0:36:09 . ..R.g%C.C./.6.
00000210 c2:9b:ad:e9:05:34:5c:42:51:f8:a1:62:ae:35:65:0c .....4\BQ..b.5e.
00000220 b7:26:84:e0:6a:01:e9:ec:b7:6c:70:8d:4b:0f:84:1b .&..j....lp.K...
00000230 bd:da:ec:75:e9:9e:53:64:bb:4b:8f:38:e7:91:98:45 ...u..Sd.K.8...E
00000240 49:1c:dc:4d:1f:39:0c:c2:81:1a:da:45:89:d3:a6:aa I..M.9.....E....
00000250 0f:a6:cf:94:69:44:b5:19:fa:48:ac:aa:27:b8:b3:d4 ....iD...H..'...
00000260 81:96:e0:3a:49:bf:e6:1e:00:00:00:80:70:49:d3:95 ...:I.......pI..
00000270 c9:28:dd:ea:7b:f4:56:1f:a9:7e:75:91:61:e1:29:16 .(..{.V..~u.a.).
00000280 94:00:eb:22:b9:17:01:84:64:ae:f2:ce:8f:14:c9:82 ..."....d.......
00000290 0e:54:62:85:dd:d8:7e:65:61:6d:3a:ac:e6:1f:66:19 .Tb...~eam:...f.
000002a0 ba:91:68:bf:93:0d:b7:28:ba:3c:fa:1a:53:39:5b:3a ..h....(....S9[:
000002b0 0f:29:31:b2:82:af:17:27:f5:ea:b0:ff:3d:ff:1a:00 .)1....'....=...
000002c0 a0:29:2b:92:bd:11:ac:7b:48:8b:ce:12:3a:8d:cc:65 .)+....{H...:..e
000002d0 ea:48:74:8a:aa:3a:6f:2a:ea:59:c7:e0:6c:93:f0:91 .Ht..:o*.Y..l...
000002e0 1e:97:0a:0e:5f:c0:51:95:9c:ec:06:6d:00:00:00:68 ...._.Q....m...h
000002f0 00:00:00:13:65:63:64:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e ....ecdsa-sha2-n
00000300 69:73:74:70:32:35:36:00:00:00:08:6e:69:73:74:70 istp256....nistp
00000310 32:35:36:00:00:00:41:04:2b:76:7c:f8:4b:a0:01:71 256...A.+v|.K..q
00000320 2f:a3:7a:2f:99:a3:2f:80:8c:27:c3:ea:78:19:a9:63 /.z/../..'..x..c
00000330 8a:97:ca:93:4a:23:75:75:39:07:70:39:d1:13:15:3c ....J#uu9.p9....
00000340 f6:ac:ca:bc:7a:34:ac:ca:a4:5f:53:4d:a8:f5:e1:a6 ....z4..._SM....
00000350 83:f1:33:8b:bc:94:ec:2a:00:00:00:33:00:00:00:0b ..3....*...3....
00000360 73:73:68:2d:65:64:32:35:35:31:39:00:00:00:20:60 ssh-ed25519... `
00000370 d5:4f:a4:06:4b:1f:ce:c1:47:33:07:6e:7c:1a:c5:ef .O..K...G3.n|...
00000380 db:ed:0d:c5:4b:1b:f1:89:c6:21:f1:52:5e:8d:45 ....K....!.R^.E

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_REQUEST_FAILURE (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)


<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0002s)
00000000 00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:80:00 ................

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:09:73:75:62:73:79:73:74:65 ........subsyste
00000010 6d:01:00:00:00:04:73:66:74:70 m.....sftp

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST (since last: 0.0032, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:01:00:00:01:55:54 ......UT

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:01:00 ....

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:09:00:00:00:05:01:00:00:00 ................
00000010 03 .

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0159, network: 0.0158s)
00000000 00:00:01:00:00:00:00:9a:00:00:00:96:02:00:00:00 ................
00000010 03:00:00:00:18:70:6f:73:69:78:2d:72:65:6e:61:6d .....posix-renam
00000020 65:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00 e@openssh.com...
00000030 01:31:00:00:00:13:73:74:61:74:76:66:73:40:6f:70 .1....statvfs@op
00000040 65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00:01:32:00:00 enssh.com....2..
00000050 00:14:66:73:74:61:74:76:66:73:40:6f:70:65:6e:73 ..fstatvfs@opens
00000060 73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00:01:32:00:00:00:14:68 sh.com....2....h
00000070 61:72:64:6c:69:6e:6b:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e ardlink@openssh.
00000080 63:6f:6d:00:00:00:01:31:00:00:00:11:66:73:79:6e com....1....fsyn
00000090 63:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00 c@openssh.com...
000000a0 01:31 .1

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0e:00:00:00:0a:10:00:00:00 ................
00000010 01:00:00:00:01:2e ......

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0003, network: 0.0003s)
00000000 00:00:01:00:00:00:00:1b:00:00:00:17:68:00:00:00 ............h...
00000010 01:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:2f:00:00:00:01:2f:00 ........./..../.
00000020 00:00:00 ...

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0059, network: 0s)
00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:28:00:00:00:24:03:00:00:00 .......(...$....
00000010 01:00:00:00:13:2f:74:6d:70:2f:61:75:64:69:74:5f ...../tmp/audit_
00000020 6c:69:6e:75:78:2e:73:68:00:00:00:1a:00:00:00:00 linux.sh........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0005, network: 0.0005s)
00000000 00:00:01:00:00:00:00:21:00:00:00:1d:65:00:00:00 .......!....e...
00000010 01:00:00:00:02:00:00:00:0c:4e:6f:20:73:75:63:68 .........No such
00000020 20:66:69:6c:65:00:00:00:00 file....
```

Comment: Could you share the PHP code and error/exception

Comment: It's part of a larger application, but you can see the code itself on Github - https://github.com/Opmantek/open-audit/blob/master/code_igniter/application/helpers/ssh_helper.php

The function in question is SCP and when we fail, we do $log->command_output = $ssh->getLog(); That output is what you see above.

Comment: You're sending the file over via SFTP - not SCP. Anyway, it's trying to open `/tmp/audit_linux.sh for writing`, creation and truncation, and it's then failing with a "no such file" error. Is that the actual name of the file?

Comment: yes, /tmp/audit_linux.sh is the file being (attempted) copied.

Comment: Maybe a `chroot` beeing applied somewhere?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I'm no Synology guru at all.

Comment: Seems I'm not the only one...   
https://serverfault.com/questions/490383/removing-chroot-jail-on-synology-diskstation-4-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems DiskStation ***does*** put you in a chroot. As per https://forum.restic.net/t/new-user-sftp-issues/165

> And sftp also puts you in your home directory, but in a chroot environment where that directory is at the root and you can’t leave.

```
mark@desktop:/$ sftp mark@192.168.1.22
mark@192.168.1.22's password: 
Connected to 192.168.1.22.
sftp> cd /tmp
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /
sftp>
```